# Can I make commit's and dispatches form methodes or hooks?

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3

Hello i'm looking for a way to make the mutation using onMounted in one of my components.
For example:

```
mutation:{
      letPrintSth(){
        console.log("hello i'm in vuex");
      }
}
```

```
onMounted:{()=>{
   this.$store.commit('letPrintSth') 
}}
```

but this way it throw err

- Property '$store' does not exist on type 'void'.

Can someone show me the proper way to do this?

Comment: personal opinion, but using `pinia` is much better

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use pinia it's not up to me. :/

Comment: If you are using `composition api` in your component, you don't have access to `this` keyword, instead you should import store before using it. [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)